# Access Abstract Interface Member C#11

Tags: c#, .net-7.0, c#-11.0

I'm trying to get the new `AdditiveIdentity` property from all of the inbuilt `INumber<T>` classes. So I'm starting with `int` (which should return 0).

However, I'm finding it difficult to actually get to this value... (I have got the .NET 7 Preview 7 installed).

I'd have thought that I'd be able to do:

```cs
int additiveIdentity = int.AdditiveIdentity;
```

But that throws an error about accessing it in a non-static context (it doesn't work in a static method either.

I've tried accessing it on an `INumber<int>`:

```cs
int additiveIdentity = INumber<int>.AdditiveIdentity;
```

That throws this error:

> UnitTest1.cs(11, 26): [CS8926] A static virtual or abstract interface member can be accessed only on a type parameter.

Given that this `AdditiveIdentity` has the signature:

```cs
public abstract static override TResult AdditiveIdentity { get; }
```

I'm a little bit stumped as to how I can actually read it...

Surely I don't have to use reflection?

Comment: Sounds like `class Generic<T> where T :  INumber<T>` you can only call `T.AdditiveIdentity`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To provide a little bit more context why this is happening - for `Int32` the [`IAdditiveIdentity<TSelf,TResult>`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.numerics.iadditiveidentity-2?view=net-7.0) interface is [explicitly implemented](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/interfaces/explicit-interface-implementation) (see the [source code](https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/blob/e05944dd74118db06d6987fe2724813950725737/src/libraries/System.Private.CoreLib/src/System/Int32.cs#L311)):

```cs
/// <inheritdoc cref="IAdditiveIdentity{TSelf, TResult}.AdditiveIdentity" />
static int IAdditiveIdentity<int, int>.AdditiveIdentity => AdditiveIdentity;
```

The approach used for ordinary instance interface methods with explicit implementation via casting to the interface is not available (at least ATM), so you need to use the generic workaround:

```cs
static T GetAdditiveIdentity<T>() where T : IAdditiveIdentity<T, T> => T.AdditiveIdentity;
```

**UPD**

As [answered](https://github.com/dotnet/csharplang/issues/4436#issuecomment-1236228833) in the discussions of the proposal for static abstract members in interfaces there are no other options ATM except for the generic indirection or using reflection. The reflection approach can look like this (strictly for explorative purposes, the generic indirection approach should be better in general case):

```cs
var properties = typeof(int).GetProperties(BindingFlags.Static | BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Public);
var propertyInfo = properties.FirstOrDefault(t => t.Name.EndsWith(".AdditiveIdentity"));
var x = (int)propertyInfo.GetValue(null);
```

Answer (score 4):

So I've found the answer, these can only be accessed when working on a generic type parameter.

So a good workaround for this is:

```cs
public static T GetAdditiveIdentity<T>() where T: INumber<T> => T.AdditiveIdentity;
```