# How to invoke static interface method via reflection

Tags: c#, reflection

How can you implement a function as follows?

```
static object GetZero(Type t)
{
  // If t implements INumberBase<TSomething>, then return INumberBase<TSomething>.Zero
  // Otherwise, throw some arbitrary Exception
}
```

My attempt so far was:

```
static object GetZero(Type t)
{
   return t
    .GetInterfaces()
    .Single(x => x.IsGenericType && !x.IsGenericTypeDefinition && x.GetGenericTypeDefinition() == typeof(INumberBase<>))
    .GetProperty("Zero", BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.Static)
    .GetValue(null);
}
```

However, under dotnet7, this fails with a fairly nasty exception. For example, GetZero(typeof(int)) throws

> System.BadImageFormatException : Bad IL format.
> at System.Reflection.MethodInvoker.Invoke(Object obj, IntPtr* args, BindingFlags invokeAttr)
> at System.Reflection.RuntimeMethodInfo.Invoke(Object obj, BindingFlags invokeAttr, Binder binder, Object[] parameters, CultureInfo culture)
> at System.Reflection.PropertyInfo.GetValue(Object obj)

Why is this implementation throwing?
Is there another way to implement this via reflection?

---

Edit:
I can work around this by adding a static method as follows

```
 static T Zero<T>() where T : INumberBase<T>
 {
     return T.Zero;
 }
```

Then having my reflection code invoke this instead of the interface property. This works, but seems .. ugly? So I'm still curious why the original code above throws.

Comment: Is Zero the actual problem or just used as example here?

Comment: Zero is actually the real use case here

Comment: Wouldn't it be then always the same as just creating an instance of the type? The default for all INumberBase types should be 0. So a Activator.CreateInstance(t) should be equivalent to what Zero delivers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Static abstract interface members can be invoked only from concrete type, i.e. something like `var i = INumberBase<int>.Zero;` (which your reflection code basically attempts to do) is invalid and will not compile.

Personally I prefer the generic indirection approach (the `Zero<T>` one, you can combine it with the reflection if needed) as far more robust, but pure reflection approach can be something like the following:

```cs
static object GetZero(Type t) => t
        .GetProperties(BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Static)
        .Where(info => info.Name.EndsWith(".Zero") || info.Name = "Zero")
        .Single()
        .GetValue(null);
```

Though it relies on the implementation details and is quite brittle (you can improve it by checking if type is `INumberBase<>` and searching first for member with name like `INumberBase< TYPE_NAME >.Zero` and then for name = `Zero`, but this quickly becomes more ugly than the generic approach).

See also [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73596226/2501279).