# Why does decimal.Radix result in a CS0117 Error?

Tags: c#, .net, generics, compiler-errors, system.numerics

**TL;DR How do I access `Decimal.Radix`?**

For the learning of it, I am trying to implement my own fraction type. The type should implement [`System.Numerics.INumber<TSelf>`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.numerics.inumber-1?view=net-8.0), which includes [`System.Numerics.INumberBase<TSelf>`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.numerics.inumberbase-1?view=net-8.0), which includes the property definition [`public static abstract int Radix { get; }`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.numerics.inumberbase-1.radix?view=net-8.0#system-numerics-inumberbase-1-radix).

[The documentation is surprisingly short](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.numerics.inumberbase-1.radix?view=net-8.0#system-numerics-inumberbase-1-radix) so I tried simple experiments to aid in understanding of what `.Radix` really means. None of these experiments could successfully access the `INumberBase<TSelf>.Radix` property of any BCL type which implements it.

I checked the documentation and introductory writings on Generic Math. The closest I came to an answer was the introductory blog post: [.NET 7 Preview 5 – Generic Math, Tanner Gooding](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/dotnet/dotnet-7-generic-math/) which had this to say on the matter, although specifically about `IFloatingPoint`:

> you can get the `Sign`, `Radix`, `Exponent`, and `Significand` out allowing you to construct the exact value as `-1^Sign * Radix^Exponent * Significand` (the standard algorithm for IEEE 754 values and which is more generally extensible to rational values).

So it seems that if a type implements either `IFloatingPoint` or `INumberBase<TSelf>` then one should be able to do something like `int a = T.Radix` and get back the base of `T`, however:

```
// .NET 7, 8
using System.Numerics;

int a = Decimal.Radix;
```

results in a [`CS0117 'decimal' does not contain a definition for 'Radix'`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/query/roslyn.query?appId=roslyn&k=k(CS0117)) whose link has explanation:

> 'type' does not contain a definition for 'identifier'.

> This error occurs in some situations when a reference is made to a member that does not exist for the data type.

**Edit for Possible Duplicate:**

The workaround found in [Access Abstract Interface Member C#11](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73588532/access-abstract-interface-member-c11):

```
public static T GetAdditiveIdentity<T>() where T: INumber<T> => T.AdditiveIdentity;
```

Works for `AdditiveIdentity` but not for `Radix`:

```
Console.WriteLine(GetRadix<decimal>());
static T GetRadix<T>() where T : INumberBase<T> => T.Radix;
// where T : INumber<T> does not change the error or message
// where T : IFloatingPoint<decimal> does not change the error or message
```

Results in a [CS0029 Cannot implicitly convert type 'int' to T](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/compiler-messages/cs0029?f1url=%3FappId%3Droslyn%26k%3Dk(CS0029)), which has information about explicit conversions.

**How do I access `Decimal.Radix`?**